# How do I redirect with locales as params in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Example

I have a home_path that is /de/home/ and one that is /en/home/ in my Rails app. How can I choose which one I want to redirect to when I have 
    redirect_to home_path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you have to redirect user based on user's locale, for example to redirect a user you can do this in your root controller:

```
 scope "/:locale", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
    root to: redirect("/%{locale}/posts", status: 302)
  end
```

Here is more tip and tricks about [handling locals](https://dhampik.com/blog/rails-routes-tricks-with-locales).